# Identity with covariant derivatives and curvature tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, derivatives

Let $\nabla_a$ be a covariant derivative, $R^a_{~~bcd}$ the curvature tensor and $w_a$ a one form. The following identity is well known (in fact I think some even define the curvature tensor through this);
$$\big[\nabla_a,\nabla_b\big]w_c=-R^d_{~~cab}w_d.$$
In this identity, may I replace $w_c$ with $\nabla_c$ and conclude that $\big[\nabla_a,\nabla_b\big]\nabla_c=-R^d_{~~cab}\nabla_d$, or is this too naive?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: If you think so Qmechanic then that is fine by me.